# How to enter inside array number - js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, fetch

When I do a fetch, as response, I recieve a array list, with numbers, and inside those numbers, are the content, but I don't now how to enter inside those numbers, and, when I'm not inside the numbers, my li, mapped with the array content, goes like: [Object, object]

[image: Response array]

This image show the response array

My code piece:

```
fetch(`https://api.dicionario-aberto.net/suffix/${suffixValue}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(suff => {

        const suffixRes = document.getElementById('suffixRes')

        console.log(suff)
        
        var str = '<ul>'
        
        suff.forEach(function(objects) {
            str += '<li>'+ objects + '</li>';
        });

        document.getElementById("suffixRes").innerHTML = str;
    })
```

Comment: What output are you wanting? How does properties `sense`, `word` & `preview` relate to what you want in HTML?

Comment: That has nothing to do with the numbers (which are the indizes of the array in your response), you are trying to print an object to your HTML. You have to access specific properties of the object inside your `forEach` loop. But I would cycle back to the basics before starting to create an app like this

Comment: you might wanna try res[index]

Comment: I want to get the ```word``` property of each number of the array, and show them in a list

Comment: '<li>'+ JSON.stringify(objects) + '</li>';

Comment: @MaurícioOliveira you can access the `word` property using the dot notation: `str += '<li>'+ objects.words + '</li>';` But I really would suggest getting to know JS basics

Comment: I got it, using: ```str += '<li>'+ JSON.stringify(objects.word) + '</li>';``` Thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: You don't need that `JSON.stringify` call.  The result is already a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the *properties* of the object you fetch.  Something like this, perhaps:

```js
const suffixValue = 'cana'

fetch(`https://api.dicionario-aberto.net/suffix/${suffixValue}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(suff => {

        const suffixRes = document.getElementById('suffixRes')

        // console.log(suff)
        
        var str = '<ul>'
        
        suff.forEach(function(object) {
            // maybe do something with "sense" too
            str += `<li>${object.word} (${object.preview})</li>`;
        });

        str += "</ul>"

        document.getElementById("suffixRes").innerHTML = str;
    })
```

```html
<div id="suffixRes" />
```

When you talk about the "numbers", that's simply the indices of the array, shown in console as numbers.  The point is that you have an *array*, an ordered collection of values.  The values are what's important, and you already deal with the fact that they're in an array by calling `forEach` on it.  Now you just need to handle the multi-property object included.

But it might be nice to look at simplifying this as well.  `forEach` is only rarely the appropriate solution.  Here you have a list of items and want to turn it into a list of `<li>`-wrapped strings.  That's better expressed with `map`.  With some additional clean-up, that might end up looking like this:

```js
const suffixValue = 'cana'

fetch(`https://api.dicionario-aberto.net/suffix/${suffixValue}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => 
        document.getElementById('suffixRes').innerHTML = 
          '<ul>' +
          res.map (({word, preview}) => `<li>${word} (${preview})</li>`).join('') +
          "</ul>"
     )
```

```html
<div id="suffixRes" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get the word property of each number of the array, and show them in a list

```
 suff.forEach(function(objects) {
        str += '<li>'+ objects.word + '</li>';
    });
```